useForm setter method not setting file
I have a React app that's attached to a Laravel backend through Inertia.js.
Inertia provides straightforward way of uploading files:
https://www.inertiajs.com/file-uploads
My code closely resembles this, but something prevents the file from being set.
This is the method that gets called when I pick a file via the picker:
    const { data, setData, post, progress, errors, } = useForm({
        recipient: '',
        recipient_mail: '',
        sum: '',
        file: null,
        filename: '',
        type: '',
    })

    const handleFileChange = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        console.log(file); // It's defined here, after selecting a valid file.
        if (file && file.type === 'application/pdf') {
            setData('file', file);
            setData('filename', file.name);
            console.log("File attached");
        } else {
            setFile(null)
            setData('file', null);
            setData('filename', '');
            console.log("No file attached");
        }
    };

However, if I put out some debug info afterwards:
    const debugClick = () => {
        console.log("data.file:", data.file); // It's always "null"
        console.log("data.filename:", data.filename); // This is set correctly
    }

While all other fields (just strings & numbers) get set correctly, file is still always null.
Needless to say, if I try to submit the form, the selected file isn't sent along. It seems like the setter method is failing for some reason.
For reference, here's how the pdf file (or one of them, as I've tried multiple files) shows up in a console.log:
File { name: "invoice_dummy.pdf", lastModified: 1725345145845, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 102020, type: "application/pdf" }
create.jsx:24:16

As an alternative I tried using React's useEffect, creating a FormData object and appending the file via formData.append(). In this case, the useEffect's setter method sets the file as expected, but nothing gets added by formData.append.
Just for completeness' sake, here's the input field as well:
                                    <input type="file"
                                        id="document_pdf"
                                        name="file"
                                        accept=".pdf,application/pdf"
                                        value={data.file}
                                        className="mt-1 block w-full"
                                        onChange={handleFileChange}
                                    />

I feel like either I'm overlooking someting obvious, or there is something about forms and files that I'm not aware of, and the Inertia.js documentation is taking it for granted.


Avoid using value={data.file} in the <input> element.
File inputs work differently from text inputs in React. Setting the value attribute on a file input may cause issues since it's intended to be controlled by the browser, not by React.

<input
    type="file"
    id="document_pdf"
    name="file"
    accept=".pdf,application/pdf"
    className="mt-1 block w-full"
    onChange={handleFileChange}
/>


Use Inertia.post() to send the FormData object with the forceFormData: true option, which tells Inertia to treat it as a file upload.

Here is the final block of code to upload file via post request:


const { data, setData, post, progress, errors } = useForm({
    recipient: '',
    recipient_mail: '',
    sum: '',
    file: null,
    filename: '',
    type: '',
});

const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    console.log(file);
    if (file && file.type === 'application/pdf') {
        setData('file', file);
        setData('filename', file.name);
        console.log("File attached");
    } else {
        setData('file', null);
        setData('filename', '');
        console.log("No file attached");
    }
};

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('recipient', data.recipient);
    formData.append('recipient_mail', data.recipient_mail);
    formData.append('sum', data.sum);

    if (data.file) {
        formData.append('file', data.file);
    }

    // Inertia sends the request as multipart/form-data
    Inertia.post('/your-endpoint', formData, {
        forceFormData: true,
        onSuccess: () => console.log("File submitted successfully"),
        onError: (errors) => console.log(errors),
    });
};


Thank you, removing value={data.file} solved the issue!
Which I find surprising, since Inertia's own documentation example has a value field on their input element. So I would never have expected that to be the root of the problem.
